# MUnit testing a flow with collection-aggregator

Tags: unit-testing, mule, munit

I am trying to write MUnit tests for my Mule flows. I want to write a test for the below flow

[image: Complete mule flow]

```
<flow name="DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Source-File-Scheduler" cronExpression="${source.pollingfrequency}" startDelay="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="InputSFTPEndpoint"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow #[payload.getClass().getName()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="#[java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE]" doc:name="GroupsizeForExceptionAggregator"/>
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()]" doc:name="corelationIdForExceptionAggregator"/>
    <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="originalPayload"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <flow-ref name="ProcessCSVFlow" doc:name="ProcessCSVFlow" />
    <exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow Strategy"/>
</flow>


 <sub-flow name="ProcessCSVFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <transformer ref="enrichWithHeaderAndEndOfFileTransformer" doc:name="headerAndEOFEnricher" />
    <set-variable variableName="outputfilename" value="#['Mercury'+server.dateTime.year+server.dateTime.month+server.dateTime.dayOfMonth+server.dateTime.hours+server.dateTime.minutes+server.dateTime.seconds+'.csv']" doc:name="outputfilename"/>
    <!-- <set-variable variableName="outputfilename" value="#['Mercury'+server.dateTime.year+':'+server.dateTime.month+':'+server.dateTime.dayOfMonth+'::'+server.dateTime.hours+':'+server.dateTime.minutes+':'+server.dateTime.seconds+'.csv']" doc:name="outputfilename"/> -->
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="DestinationSFTP" host="${destination.host}" port="22" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="DestinationSFTP"
    outputPattern="#[outputfilename]" path="${destination.path}" user="${destination.username}" password="${destination.password}"/>
    <gzip-compress-transformer/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="InputSFTP" host="${source.host}" port="22" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SourceArchiveSFTP" 
    outputPattern="#[outputfilename].gzip" path="Archive" user="${source.username}" password="${source.password}"/>
    <component doc:name="Delete Read File">
        <singleton-object class="component.DeleteProcessedFileComponent">
            <property key="host" value="${source.host}"/>
            <property key="username" value="${source.username}"/>
            <property key="password" value="${source.password}"/>
            <property key="workingDirectory" value="${source.path}"/>
        </singleton-object>
    </component>
    <parse-template location="successmessagetemplate.txt" doc:name="Success Template"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${smtp.from.address}" password="${smtp.from.password}" 
                            to="${smtp.to.address}" from="${smtp.from.address}" subject="${mail.success.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" 
                            doc:name="SuccessEmail" connector-ref="Gmail"/>
    <logger message="Process completed successfully" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Exception handling block

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="Default_Exception_Strategy">
    <flow-ref name="ExceptionHandlingSubflow" doc:name="ExceptionHandlingSubflow"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>

<sub-flow name="ExceptionHandlingSubflow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <collection-aggregator timeout="60000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Exception Aggregator"/>
    <logger message="Exception has occured Payload is #[payload] and Message is #[message]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <parse-template location="errormessagetemplate.txt" doc:name="Error Template"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${smtp.from.address}" password="${smtp.from.password}"
                            to="${smtp.to.address}" from="${smtp.from.address}" subject="${mail.failure.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" 
                            doc:name="ErrorEmail" connector-ref="Gmail"/>
</sub-flow>
```

The interesting bit is the exception sub-flow, especially the collection-aggregator

My unit test is

```
@Test
public void whenMultipleExceptionsOccurInFlow_itShouldSendOnlyOneFailureEmail() throws Exception {
    whenMessageProcessor("collection-aggregator")
            .withAttributes(attribute("name").ofNamespace("doc").withValue("Exception Aggregator")).thenReturnSameEvent();

    destinationSFTP.thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Dummy Exception destinationSFTP"));

    MuleEvent testEvent = PropertyEnricher.enrich(testEvent(IOUtils.toInputStream("hello,dummy,payload"))).get();

    runFlow("DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow", testEvent);

    verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").ofNamespace("smtp")
            .withAttributes(attribute("name").ofNamespace("doc").withValue("ErrorEmail"))
            .times(1);
}
```

Now if I do not mock the collection aggregator out my test does not pass, I can understand that this is tricky as the aggregator has a "pause" within it and hence is not an ideal candidate for a unit test, however from a technical standpoint I want to understand what is causing the unit test to fail (when collection-aggregator is not mocked).

My test fails when the collection-aggregator is not mocked.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: On smtp:outbound-endpoint.Expected 1 but got 0 calls
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at org.mule.munit.common.mocking.MunitVerifier.times(MunitVerifier.java:86)
    at nz.co.mightyriver.ProcessCsvTest.whenMultipleExceptionsOccurInFlow_itShouldSendOnlyOneFailureEmail(ProcessCsvTest.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying to reproduce this issue:

**Production Code**

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="stack-munit-and-aggregationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#['lalero_' + new java.util.Date().toString()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="stack-munit-and-aggregationSub_Flow" doc:name="stack-munit-and-aggregationSub_Flow"/>
        <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#[payload.toString()]"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="stack-munit-and-aggregationSub_Flow">
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator" timeout="10"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

**Test Code**

```
package org.mule.munit;

import org.junit.Assert; import org.junit.Test; import org.mule.api.MuleEvent; import org.mule.api.MuleException; import org.mule.munit.runner.functional.FunctionalMunitSuite;

public class TheTest extends FunctionalMunitSuite {

    @Test
    public void aTest() throws MuleException, Exception {    MuleEvent event = runFlow("stack-munit-and-aggregationFlow", testEvent(""));

    String payload = (String) event.getMessage().getPayload();

    Assert.assertTrue(payload.contains("lalero"));
    } }
```

If you check this code you'll notice that I'm not mocking out the collection aggregator. After a few tests I wasn't  able to reproduce your error.

I think the issue could somewhere else. 
Could you please share you're code so I can investigate further?

World of warning though, due to an issue discovered in:
[How to mock a Java component within Mule Flow using MUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909790/how-to-mock-a-java-component-within-mule-flow-using-munit/29928595#29928595)

You may find a problem if you try to directly test your sub-flow ExceptionHandlingSubFlow. But as you were not doing that in your example code I don't think those two are related.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking so much interest, have updated my question with requested details, Also I got the exception printed wrong the last time (not sure how I mucked up though), so now my assertion fails if the aggregation router is not mocked.

Comment: Hi there, 

For what I see, it seems that the error is in the flow with the aggregation MP (which BTW you didn't post). 

Any way I would suggest that you try to replicate your MUnit test, where you can debug the mule flows. If it fails when it's not mocked out (the aggregation) probably something in the payload reaching that MP is not what's expected (I reckon an exception). I don't see at this point nothing that points to a MUnit bug :(

Comment: Thanks, I have added the exception handling block which uses the collection-aggregator would be nice if you could have a look.

Comment: so I see no actual error in the code, what's the content of the message when it gets to the aggregation MP?